# How should I code a jQuery plugin to use it like String.myPlugin() instead of Selector.myPlugin()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, jquery-plugins, arguments

I've been playing with jQuery lately and I need now a function for strings, and I want to execute it like this:

```
var str = "mystring";
if( str.myPlugin( ) )
{

}
```

But all the examples I found for jquery plugins can only be used like `$(selector).myPlugin();`If I apply them to a string i get "... is not a function".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a string, what you are really creating is a new instance of the `String` object.

```
var str = new String("mystring");
```

You can add methods to all instances of the object using the object's prototype.

```
String.prototype.myPlugin = function(){
  alert("worky!");
}

var str = "mystring";
str.myPlugin();
```

Adding new methods to native objects such as the `String` object is usually frowned upon due to possible name conflicts.

Edit: just to add clarification.

This is not a method of jQuery and jQuery is not required to create these kinds of methods.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this github https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns